# Universal DBNull check

Tags: c#, database

I have a VB.Net function that is useful for checking if a database record is null or not, and replace it with a default value if it is.

```
Public Function NZ(input As Object, Optional ifNull As Object = "") As Object
    If IsDBNull(input) Or input Is Nothing Then
        Return ifNull
    Else
        Return input
    End If
End Function
```

I'm trying to get the same functionality in C#, but it doesn't like using objects the same way.

The closest I've gotten is

```
    public static object NZ(object input, object ifNull)
    {
        if(input == DBNull.Value || input == null)
        {
            return ifNull;
        }
        else
        {
            return input;
        }
    }
```

but I get several errors with "cannot convert object to string" and the like.
I have tried to make a more specific version

```
    public static string NZ(string input, string ifNull)
    {
        if (input == DBNull.Value || input == null)
        {
            return ifNull;
        }
        else
        {
            return input;
        }
    }
```

but that gives a "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type string and DBNull"

I'm hoping there is an easy way to do this.

Comment: How are you trying to use this method?

Comment: What `OPTION STRICT` settings is in force for that VB.Net code? I suspect it's off, which means the C# equivalent should be using `dynamic` far more than `object`. Also VB's `Nothing` is closer to `default` than `null`.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Something like this: string lineNum = DataClass.NZ(row.Field<string>("LineNum"),""); int ID = DataClass.NZ(row.Field<int>("ID"),0);

Comment: Your first function will compile just fine. I suspect the problem comes when you try to use the object so produced without casting it first, which has nothing to do with the `DBNull` check. There should not normally be any need for a method like this because methods returning `DBNull` are typically part of classes that also contain checks and typed access (`Row.Field`, `DbDataReader.IsDBNull`, etc.) In particular, `row.Field<string>` will know to return `null` on a `DBNull`, and for `int` you can use `row.Field<int?>`, giving a nullable int (i.e. `row.Field<int?>("ID") ?? 0`).

Comment: @AndyD273 I'm pretty sure that `row.Field<string>("LineNum");` will return `null` if the value is `DbNull` so you'd just do `row.Field<string>("LineNum") ?? "";` instead.

Comment: @juharr I like the ?? idea, but apparently it can't be used on non-string types. I'm hoping to have something where I can pass through any type and have it check for dbnull

Comment: `??` applies to any nullable type, not just `string`. All value types like `int` have nullable counterparts (`int?`). A separate function for this can't be written in a type-safe way (`T DefaultIfDbNull<T>(object t, T valueIfNull) => t is null || t == DBNull.Value ? valueIfNull : (T) t;` fails if `t` is not actually of type `T`), and it's not necessary, since `.Field<T>` already takes care of the typing.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Oh, that works. I'm fairly new to C#, so nullable types are a new concept. Thanks for that. Also, apparently VB.net has nullable types too, and I've just never run into one, so I've learned two new things today.

Answer (score 2):

Use Convert.IsDbNull

The code will be something like this:

```
 public static string NZ(object input, string ifNull)
    {
        return Convert.IsDbNull(input) ? ifNull : input;
    }
```

If you want it to be more concise, write an extension method:

```
public static class DbNullExt
{
      public static string ValueOrDefault(this object input, string ifNull)
      => Convert.IsDbNull(input) ? ifNull : input?.ToString();

      public static string ValueOrDefaultIfDbNullOrNull(this object input, string ifNull)
      => Convert.IsDbNull(input) ? ifNull : input?.ToString() ?? ifNull;
}
```

And then simply invoke it as

```
var valueOrDefault = input.ValueOrDefault("ifItIsDbNull");
```

Comment: Would I have to have a different function for each data type? ie: string, int, bool, datetime

Comment: Yes. Or else you can use Generics.

Comment: Calling `Convert.IsDbNull` on a `string` will always return `false` because `DbNull` is a completely different type.

Comment: Now you're types mismatch.  You'd need to do `input.ToString()`

Comment: Null check is redundant if you are sure that this function is guaranteed to be invoked only on the values directly obtained from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Information.IsDBNull](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.information.isdbnull?view=net-5.0)

```
public object NZ(object input, object ifNull)
{
    if (Information.IsDBNull(input) || input == null)
        return ifNull;
    else
        return input;
}
```